# Find whether the sequence is convergent .

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Find whether the sequence $(a_n)$ given by $a_{n+1}= \sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{a_{n-1}}$, where $a_1=1$ and $a_2=2$, is convergent.
So , $a_{n+1}-a_{n}= \sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt{a_{n-1}} -a_n \implies         \sqrt{a_n}(1-\sqrt{a_n})+ \sqrt{a_{n-1}}.$

Now I assumed the sequence is $>1$ and I showed it by induction  then ,

$a_{n+1}-a_{n} < \sqrt{a_{n-1}}$.Any help from here ?

Comment: What do you mean by “the sequence”? $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt{a_{n-1}}$ does not define a singe sequence. What is $a_1$?

Comment: And I suppose there is a typo in your second line? The expression on the right hand side of $\Rightarrow$ is not an expression.

Comment: Note:  $a=\sqrt a+\sqrt a\implies a=4$ or $a=0$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner or $a=0$

Comment: Ad the main question: Typically, for recursively defined sequences, one first shows that these are convergent and then takes the limit on both sides of the definition to obtain the limit value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We show that the sequence is convergent by showing that it's bounded and monotone.

---

**Claim 1.** $2 \le a_n \le 4$ for all $n \ge 2.$
*Proof.* We prove this via induction. For $n = 2, 3$, it is manually verified.
Let $P(n)$ denote the statement "$2 \le a_n \le 4$".

Assume that $n \ge 4$ and that $P(k)$ is true for all $2 \le k \le n-1$. We prove that $P(n)$ is true.
By hypothesis, we have
\begin{align}
a_n &= \sqrt{a_{n-1}} + \sqrt{a_{n-2}}\\
&\ge \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2} = 2\sqrt{2}\\
&\ge2.
\end{align}
Similarly, we have
\begin{align}
a_n &= \sqrt{a_{n-1}} + \sqrt{a_{n-2}}\\
&\le \sqrt{4} + \sqrt{4}\\
&=4.
\end{align}

This proves the statement.

---

**Claim 2.** $a_n \le a_{n+1}$ for all $n \ge 1$.
*Proof.* Let $P(n)$ denote the statement "$a_n \le a_{n+1}$".
$P(n)$ can be manually verified for $n = 1, 2, 3.$
Assume that $n \ge 4$ and that $P(k)$ is true for all $1 \le k \le n-1$. We prove that $P(n)$ is true.
Using the hypothesis, we see that $$a_n \ge a_{n-1} \ge a_{n-2}.$$
(Note that $n \ge 3$, so all these terms are defined.)
By the previous claim, we also see that all the terms are positive and thus, we can conclude
$$\sqrt{a_n} \ge \sqrt{a_{n-2}}. \quad (*)$$

Now, we have
\begin{align}
a_{n+1} - a_n &= \sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt{a_{n-1}} - \sqrt{a_{n-1}} - \sqrt{a_{n-2}}\\
&= \sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{a_{n-2}}\\
&\ge 0.
\end{align}
The last inequality followed using $(*)$.
This proves this claim as well.

---

By Claim 1, the sequence is bounded and by Claim 2, the sequence is monotone. Thus, the sequence converges. (The value of the limit can be found to be $4$.)

Comment: The sequence is not increasing if you start counting like $a_3=2.4142$,$a_4=1.9566$,$a_5=1.532140$

Comment: The value of $a_4$ is $\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1} + \sqrt{2} = 2.967... > a_3$ and similarly, $a_5$ is also greater than $a_4$.